# BigQuery export table json using API

Tags: google-bigquery

I exported data of the dataset of BigQuery using  API to JSON file, but the JSON that I download has a properties saved as array object with key name as "V" instead of original name of property.

I don't want to export the table fo dataset to Google Storage, nor to execute a specified query.

I need to get the table data of the dataset with the orginal schema using the api to json file.

I am using the api:

Function: 
Tabledata: list: Retrieves table data from a specified set of rows.
[https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list#request](http://I%20exported%20data%20of%20the%20dataset%20of%20BigQuery%20using%20%20API%20to%20JSON%20file,%20but%20the%20JSON%20that%20I%20download%20has%20a%20properties%20saved%20as%20array%20object%20with%20key%20name%20as%20%22V%22%20instead%20of%20original%20name%20of%20property.%20%20I%20don't%20want%20to%20export%20the%20table%20fo%20dataset%20to%20Google%20Storage,%20nor%20to%20execute%20a%20specified%20query.%20%20I%20need%20to%20get%20the%20table%20data%20of%20the%20dataset%20with%20the%20orginal%20schema%20using%20the%20api%20to%20json%20file.%20%20I%20am%20using%20the%20api:%20%20Function:%20%20Tabledata:%20list:%20Retrieves%20table%20data%20from%20a%20specified%20set%20of%20rows.%20https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list#request%20%20Function%20%20Tables:%20get%20This%20method%20does%20not%20return%20the%20data%20in%20the%20table,%20it%20only%20returns%20the%20table%20resource,%20which%20describes%20the%20structure%20of%20this%20table.%20https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get#request)

Function 
Tables: get This method does not return the data in the table, it only returns the table resource, which describes the structure of this table.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get#request

Thank you,

Best regards,